# Mongodb aggregate to find record that has both value of a boolean

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have these documents:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "condition": true
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "condition": false
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "condition": true
    },
]
```

In this case I want the output to be `"id": 1`, since it has `condition` as both `true` and `false` (`"id": 2` only has `condition` as `true`, so it does not qualify)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `$setIsSubset` for the generic case of `n` out of `m` wanted conditions:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {
      _id: "$id",
      conditions: {$addToSet: "$condition"}
  }},
  {$match: {$expr: {
        $setIsSubset: [
          [true, false],
          "$conditions"
        ]
      }
  }},
  {$project: {id: 1}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h4ZbsMj1Kfw)

Comment: I didn't know about that aggregation! Thank you, it works well.

Comment: i didnt know about setIsSubset either this is nice

Answer (score 1):

you could create an aggregation pipeline in a way first group by `id` and get an array of `conditions`. then check if the condition array has true and false and create condition existing fields `cond_true`,`cond_false`.
If both the `cond_true` and `cond_false` are `true` it is a match.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id",
      conditions: { $push: "$condition" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      id: "$_id",
      cond_true: { $in: [ true, "$conditions" ] },
      cond_false: { $in: [ false, "$conditions" ] }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: { cond_true: true, cond_false: true }
  },
  {
    $project: { id: 1 }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y03SMzU6zpz)

Comment: Very clever solution! I'm gonna go with the other answer though since it has less stages, but thank you for the idea!

Comment: @Kise yes i would go for that too